# Error While Running python manage.py shell

Tags: python, django, django-manage.py

I'm following the documentation of Django, and I've encountered a problem running this command: 
    python manage.py shell

This is the error I get:

```
File "manage.py", line 7
  from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and space in indentation
```

I realize what it means, but I don't know how to edit my manage.py file so it works. I might have accidentally edited the indentations and now I don't know how to revert.

This is what my manage.py file currently looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "polling.settings")
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using a mix of tabs and spaces as indentions in your `manage.py` file. Use a text editor such as SublimeText that displays the whitespaces as spaces/tabs so you can easily change them.

See http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces for more info.

Comment: I use notepad++ and it shows the indentations! I just don't know how I should edit them.

Comment: Convert all tabs to 4 spaces or vice versa. Don't use a mixture of both.

Comment: You can set notepad++ to convert ident with 4 spaces. Do this.

Answer (score 0):

Look carefully through `manage.py`. Line 7 in particular. You are using both tabs and spaces as indentation.